# Проблема с фиксированным меню (позиционирование)

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

Есть фиксированное меню, при скролле вниз элемент `.time` с позиционирование `relative` заходит на границы данного меню. Как исправить данную проблему?

Изначальное положение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При скролле вниз время заходит на навигацию[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основной код

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    background-color: #15c5d5;
    text-align: center;
}

.time {
    position: relative;
    left: 480px;
    top: -41px;
}

 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/" title="Main Page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/comments" title="Add a comment">Comments</a></li>
            <li><select><option>Eng</option><option>Rus</option></select></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>


<div>
   <ul>
       <li class="time">вставка времени комментария</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Подтолкните хотя бы. Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы я понял случайно. Если есть фиксированное меню и на странице есть элементы с позиционированием `relative`. То нужно просто поставить `z-index: 999;` в меню. Тогда элементы `relative` не будут наступать на меню.

```
nav {
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 40px 0px;
   background-color: green;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 999; # обязательно 
}

div {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите позиционирование relative у селектора .time. Тогда проблема исчезнет. Позиционирование здесь простое, поэтому для отступа сверху блока .time можно брать простое margin-top;

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    background-color: #15c5d5;
    text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.time {
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/" title="Main Page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/comments" title="Add a comment">Comments</a></li>
            <li><select><option>Eng</option><option>Rus</option></select></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>


<div>
   <ul>
       <li class="time">вставка времени комментария</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```